# How to debug sphinx indexer errors for CSV files: "not all columns found"?

Tags: csv, sphinx

I'm using sphinx `indexer` on a `.csv.gz` file.

Some files return errors:

> not all columns found (found=7, total=8, line=3766, pos=85, docid=822587)

How can I use this information to find the problem with my compressed csv file?

For example, is the problem with line 3766 of the uncompressed CSV file? Or is it *row* 3766? Or is it line 3766 of the compressed file? etc.

Comment: Surely it would just been quicker (than writing this whole message!) to look at line 3766 and find out if the message refers to it? Should even have the id 822587 in it, making it easy to identify.

Comment: Thanks! So sounds like `line` is likely the CSV line number (not file line number), `docid` is the ID column?